# How to give a custom id to a heading in markdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I am using `markdown to jsx` as markdown parser. How can I give a custom id to a heading in markdown?
`### Generation of keys {#custom-id}` is giving:

```html
<h3 id="generation-of-keys-custom-id">Generation of keys {#key-generation}</h3>
```

but I want:

```html
<h3 id="custom-id">Generation of keys </h3>
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the simple markdown format, but one solution is to use custom jsx if the parser you are using supports it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with [markdown-to-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) as it currently exists. You can change the ID by writing some custom `slugify` function on the [`options` argument](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx#optionsslugify) but you won't be able to change the content within the heading.

Here [is the relevant code](https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx/blob/abb0209a48396ce02919e060ca92617b67ca540d/index.tsx#L1213-L1236) for how it creates `Heading` components from JSX. [Here is the Regular Expression](https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx/blob/abb0209a48396ce02919e060ca92617b67ca540d/index.tsx#L277) it uses to parse out the heading:

```js
/^ *(#{1,6}) *([^\n]+?)(?: +#*)?(?:\n *)*(?:\n|$)/
```

Visualized as

[image: Visualization of above regular expression]

You can see that they capture two pieces of information:

1. The "level" (aka `h1` through `h6`)
2. And the text of the heading

Back to the library, in the `_parse` function, we return an Object from our regular expression match:

```js
_parse(capture, parse, state) {
  return {
    content: parseInline(parse, capture[2], state),
    id: options.slugify(capture[2]),
    level: capture[1].length,
  }
},
```

You can see they create an `id` property using that `slugify` options (which has a sane default). Here is your opportunity to change how the ID is formed.

However, you can see the `content` doesn't have any room for customization.

The library then uses a `_react` function to finally transform the parsed object into a JSX node:

```js
_react(node, output, state) {
  node.tag = `h${node.level}`;
  return (
    <node.tag id={node.id} key={state._key}>
      {output(node.content, state)}
    </node.tag>
  )
},
```

I'd look into opening a PR on the repository, which has a 3rd capturing group using some pre-defined syntax (perhaps with `{#custom-id-here}` as you have it). Otherwise, you can open a PR to provide another optional function that transforms the `content` before it is passed off to the final `_react` call.

Comment: That was awesome.
But all my headings are repeated twice. I have listed all the heading at one place and then I have a description  on individual heading. I want to give id to the heading that comes second. How to attain that ???
Even if I do slugify I need to return same id for repeated heading.

Comment: I'd probably look to using [custom overrides](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx#optionsoverrides---rendering-arbitrary-react-components) since that will give you more control.